# Excel macros how to autofill cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

When I run a macro, the value in cell `AB2` changes. I want another macro named copyStuff to run automatically when the value in cell `AB2` changes to 6. Please help.

Comment: Can we take a look at what code you currently have for your macro?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have been able to write the macro using examples on the net.In fact I have combined 3 macros into 1.I have added the codes for the second and third macros to the first one and it is working.The code for the second macro to copy values to subsequent rows on sheet 2 when value of cell AB2 in sheet 1 is 6 is as follows

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have been able to write the macro using examples on the net.In fact I have combined 3 macros into 1.I have added the codes for the second and third macros to the first one and it is working.The code for the second macro to copy values to subsequent rows on sheet 2 when value of cell AB2  is 6 is as follows.       If Range("ab2").Value = 6 Then        Range("Ai16:an16").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If
And the code to run the macro several times                        'Sub GG()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Range("z1")
newmac
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheet_Change event to trigger your code. To do this open the VBA editor window (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). In the project explorer, double click the sheet on which you want to monitor `AB2` (listed under Microsoft Excel Objects).

[image]

Then, paste in the following code. If `copyStuff` is in a separate module, this should work right away.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Check if changed range includes AB2. If so, check value of AB2.
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AB2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Range("AB2").Value = 6 Then
        Call copyStuff
    End If
End If
End Sub
```